# RRULE parsing in Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, icalendar, rrule, libical

**The goal:** to generate a list of timestamps, each representing an event occurrance, from an RRULE string (i.e. `FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=8;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH`) and a starting timestamp.
Since these times will be changed at the whim of a user, postgresql is desired for (1) it's quality of strict business logic and (2) triggers (auto-update rows when a value changes)

**Alternative Solution:**

I ended up using plpythonu (python language for postgresql). The [dateutil library](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) has a great rrule parser.

```
mydatabase=# CREATE FUNCTION parse_occurrences(rule text, start timestamp) RETURNS timestamp[] AS
mydatabase-# 'from dateutil.rrule import *
mydatabase'# from dateutil.parser import *
mydatabase'# import datetime
mydatabase'# dates = list(rrulestr(rule, dtstart=parse(start)))
mydatabase'# return [str(a)[0:10] for a in dates]'
mydatabase-# LANGUAGE plpythonu;
CREATE FUNCTION
mydatabase=# SELECT parse_occurrences('FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=8;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH'::text, now()::timestamp);                                                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"2013-02-14 00:00:00","2013-02-26 00:00:00","2013-02-28 00:00:00","2013-03-12 00:00:00","2013-03-14 00:00:00","2013-03-26 00:00:00","2013-03-28 00:00:00","2013-04-09 00:00:00"}
```

**The (original) endeavor:** to connect the [C-library libical](https://github.com/Marketcircle/libical) with [Postgresql C-Extensions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-c.html). This requires a specialized C program to do the following: (1) convert postgresql data types to C-data types, (2) execute all necessary C-library functions, and (3) return the data in postgresql formats using the header file "postgres.h".

**The Connector File: ical_recur.c**

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "icalrecur.h"
#include <time.h> /* for time() */
#include "fmgr.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(get_occurrences);

Datum
get_occurrences(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
        //char*        rule; /* rule string */
        time_t      start; /* start time */
        int         count;
        char        *rrule;

       // *rule = PG_GETARG_CHAR(0);
        start = (time_t) PG_GETARG_INT32(1);
        count = (int) PG_GETARG_INT32(2);
        *rrule = PG_GETARG_CHAR(0);

        time_t   *result[count]; /* output array */

        icalrecur_expand_recurrence(rrule, start, count, *result);

        PG_RETURN_INT32(*result);
}
```

**Preparing the Connector File:**

Step 1: Compile to the object file, create the shared object, copy to the location postgresql looks for C-extensions

```
sudo gcc -I/usr/local/libical/lib -lical -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.2/server -fpic -c ical_recur.c
sudo gcc -shared -L/usr/local/libical/lib -lical -o ical_recur.so ical_recur.o
sudo cp ical_recur.so /usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/
```

Step 2: Add the libical lib folder to be found by C & reload the configuration

```
sudo echo "/usr/local/libical/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

**Testing the Connector File:**

Step 1: Load up psql and CREATE the FUNCTION

```
psql
mydatabase=# CREATE FUNCTION get_occurrences(text, integer, integer) RETURNS int[]
mydatabase=- AS '$libdir/ical_recur', 'get_occurrences'
mydatabase=- LANGUAGE C STRICT;
CREATE FUNCTION
mydatabase=#
```

**Current Roadblock:**

The C-function has crashed the postgresql server.

```
psql (9.2.3)
Type "help" for help.

mydatabase=# SELECT get_occurrences('FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=8;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH', now()::timestamp, 5);
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!>
```

The logs...

```
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC LOG:  server process (PID 22733) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault

2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT get_occurrences('FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=8;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH', now()::timestamp, 5);
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2013-02-11 21:47:26 UTC
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC LOG:  redo starts at 0/1903A0C
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC LOG:  record with zero length at 0/190E1E0
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC LOG:  redo done at 0/190E1B8
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2013-02-11 22:03:29.641161+00
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2013-02-11 22:03:33 UTC LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

**UPDATED:**

I've updated the method to address some suggestions.

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "icalrecur.h"
#include <time.h> /* for time() */
#include "fmgr.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(get_occurrences);

Datum
get_occurrences(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
        time_t start = (time_t) PG_GETARG_INT32(1); /* convert int to time_t */
        int count = PG_GETARG_INT32(2);
        char rrule = PG_GETARG_CHAR(0);

        char *_rrule = &rrule; /* icalrecur wants a pointer to the rrule */

        time_t  result[count]; /* instantiate the output array */

        int success = icalrecur_expand_recurrence(_rrule, start, count, result);

        /* convert time_t values to int */
        int *output = malloc(sizeof(result));

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < (int) (sizeof(result) / sizeof(result[0]) - 1); i++){
                output[i] = (int) result[i];
        }

        if(success != 1){
                PG_RETURN_INT32(0);
        } else {
                PG_RETURN_INT32(output);
        }
}
```

Building with..

```
sudo gcc -Wall -Wextra -l/usr/local/libical/lib/ical -I/usr/local/libical/include/libical -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.2/server -fpic -c ical_recur.c
sudo gcc -Wall -shared -static -L/usr/local/libical/lib -lical -o ical_recur.so ical_recur.o
sudo cp libical.so /usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/lib/
```

Enter database & execute with..

```
mydb=# CREATE FUNCTION get_occurrences(text, integer, integer) RETURNS int[]
AS '$libdir/ical_recur', 'get_occurrences'
LANGUAGE C STRICT;
CREATE FUNCTION
mydb=# SELECT get_occurrences('FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=8;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH', 1360690024, 5);
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!> \q
```

Same log output. The [documentation](http://libical.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.43-3/icalrecur_8c_488780da8434731021af8d791b087b77.html#488780da8434731021af8d791b087b77) notes the parameters:

> int icalrecur_expand_recurrence(char * rule, time_t start, int count, time_t * array)

**Question:** How can we get this to work without postgres crashing?

Comment: Kind of the definition of "too localized."

Comment: Probably, but I figured generating event occurrences from an rrule string within postgres is a good thing to post and discuss.

Comment: Can this post be made more succinct, i.e. can the updates be compacted into a single, cohesive, concise post?  It feels like reading a story which is a very slow medium of information.

Comment: There we go, cut 180 lines out :) sorry for the play-by-play!

Comment: Is it succinct enough? :)

Comment: What else have you tried?  Have you gotten any C extensions to work?  If not then post the simplest example, if so then research the difference.

Comment: That's the direction I was thinking -- I'm getting the C-function alone w/o postgresql to compile and run now. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that next as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two obvious pointer-related flaws in the code shown:

**First:**

```
    *rrule = PG_GETARG_CHAR(0);
```

At this point of execution, `rrule` is a non-initialized pointer, and this instruction tries to write a char into the random location it points to. This generally causes the kind of crash you're seeing.

**Second:**

```
time_t   *result[count]; /* output array */

icalrecur_expand_recurrence(rrule, start, count, *result);
```

`result` should be an array of `time_t`, not an array of `time_t*`, and it should be passed as `result`, not `*result` which again is not initialized at this point.

Comment: But now it has 2 new problems: this malloc() is never freed and PG_RETURN_INT32 should not have a pointer passed to it

Comment: I ended up using python via dateutil.rrule library :) solved it in 5 lines. Maybe not as efficient, but it did the job. Thanks for your help, Daniel.

Comment: On your note, the postgresql documentation mentions to pass-by-reference when there is a var of variable length. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-c.html#AEN52593 and I also read somewhere that mem doesn't really have to be freed here (perhaps not best practice, though) since postgres does it automatically once the function call ends.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use [this](https://github.com/petropavel13/pg_rrule) extension for postgresql.

Example usage:

```
SELECT * FROM
     unnest(
         rrule_get_occurrences('FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;WKST=MO;UNTIL=20200101T045102Z;BYDAY=SA;BYHOUR=10;BYMINUTE=51;BYSECOND=2'::rrule,
             '2019-12-07 10:51:02+00'::timestamp with time zone)
     );

          unnest
 ------------------------
  2019-12-07 10:51:02+00
  2019-12-14 10:51:02+00
  2019-12-21 10:51:02+00
  2019-12-28 10:51:02+00
 (4 rows)
```